# Insertar datos en Tabla con Identity

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Como inserto datos en una tabla con identity. Quiero ingresar datos pero la columna inicial lleva identity y quiero saber si se puede apagar sin provocar ningún daño a la base de datos o de que manera puedo ingresar datos.

Comment: Si dejaste la columna como Identity, eso significa que se va a generar un numero autoincrementable, ten en cuenta eso. Tu no debes hacer nada al insertar datos

Answer (score 0):

Para habilitar la inserción manual de valores en la columna identity usa lo siguiente antes de la inserción :

`SET IDENTITY_INSERT nombreTabla ON;`

`insert into tabla values(...)`